# Do I have to use ref when passing current DOM-element?

Tags: reactjs

I have a function called `this.fullscreen`, it needs to know what function it's referencing, I'm doing this with `this.refs` now, but there should be a simpler way to access the current element?

```
    <div ref='thumbs' style={{
      display: 'flex',
      paddingTop: '20px',
      ...this.fullscreen(this.refs.thumbs, 0.208, 0.772)
    }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `.bind(this)`

```
<div ref='thumbs' style={{
  display: 'flex',
  paddingTop: '20px',
  ...this.fullscreen.bind(this, 0.208, 0.772)
}}>
```

Comment: If I need the original this object forexample to access state, can I get that somehow?

Comment: this doesn't work at all, I tried `<div style={this.fullscreen2.bind(this)}>` and   `fullscreen2 () { console.log('test') }` but it doesn't get triggered.